# PHP - And bulk retrieval of API stats

Tags: php, api, bit.ly

I've been looking around for the best way to retrieve stats from systems like bit.ly where you have a lot of URLs and I want to keep my system updated once an hour or so.

What's the best approach on PHP? A simple php CRON job that run through the list 15 at a time (or whatever the api limit is at the other end)? Or an php extension? Seems like it could be a big hit once the number of records gets large.

Anyone got any tips or examples on this? I have a solution in my head, but I'm intrigued as to how other's approach it as it doesn't seem to be an overly talked about topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of stats from which systems do you want to collect? I guess the operators of those systems won't be pleased by that. By time you'd have all their data. Often times that is the reason for limited APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Bit.ly does give you 15 results at once, so yeah, you can setup a cron job, to run 24/7 this way it'll balance out the busy times during the day with slow times at night.

Here's the direct link to the documentation for the clicks:

http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/clicks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this one https://github.com/TareqBajjlay/Dev 
its not OOP, it was a single page, i believe this should help.